# How to enable HTML5 on iPad with safari or opera mini browser?

Tags: html

I have just installed a gateone server, a software that enable you to ssh other hosts just with a html5 browser, I could do this with Chrome on Windows 7, but it won't work in ipad's default browser - safari , and I just installed a Opera Mini in App Store, but it also won't work.

You can also use it if it will you , guys . the address is https://www.myciscolab.net/

Comment: There's no such thing as a "html5 browser"

Comment: @Truth reading that as "a browser supporting html5" it does (sort of) exist

Comment: @Jasper: **still** doesn't exist. There's no browser currently supporting HTML5 fully. HTML is divided into modules, and some browser support some of the modules. None support all though, therefore there is no "browser supporting html5". OP needs to redefine exactly what he needs.

Comment: @Truth Yes, I know. That's why I said "sort of", as this deeper explanation wasn't there in your original comment. However, this comment put in the context of iOS could well be the answer to this question all together

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 is partly supported by safari, so the HTML5 you use on your website is probably not supported by Safari or Opera Mini. You could use websites like http://www.browsercompatible.com to determine which features of HTML5 you can use and which you can't. There are other websites as well [click here](http://fmbip.com/litmus/)